# Invalid variables error in SolveValues when using an array of variables

Tags: equation-solving, syntax, variable-definitions

I was attempting to run some code similar to the simple example below.

```
coeffVec = Array[coeff, 2];
sols = SolveValues[2 <= Total[coeffVec] <= 4, coeffVec, NonNegativeIntegers]
```

However I've getting the error

```
SolveValues:"\!\(\*RowBox[{\"\\b\", \" \", RowBox[{\"coeff\", \"[\", \"1\", \"]\"}]}]\) is not a valid variable."
```

If I enter my variables manually then everything seems to work fine. For instance, see the code below.

```
solsTemp = 
 SolveValues[2 <= coeff[1] + coeff[2] <= 4, {coeff[1], coeff[2]}, NonNegativeIntegers]
```

What is the difference between entering it manually rather than using `Array[coeff, 2]`? I would prefer use something like `Array[coeff, 2]` because I am dealing with a large number of variables so manually typing things out explicitly is not practical.

To spot the difference, I ran `FullForm[coeffVec]` and obtained

```
List[Times[\010,coeff[1]],Times[\010,coeff[2]],Times[\010,coeff[3]]].
```

This is not what I was expecting, which I suppose is why I am running into an issue. What are the `\010` factors appearing here?

Comment: Either start with `Clear[coeff, coeffVec]` or start with a fresh kernel.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I've tried both already. Neither help in my original worksheet, even if I run ```Clear[coeff, coeffVec]``` immediately before the first two lines of code from my post above, with nothing else in between. However if I start a fresh worksheet with a fresh kernel and copy across only those two lines of code, then it works fine. Any idea what the issue is here? Is ```\010``` a pointer to use ```coeff[i]``` values from another kernel/context?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into a (new) notebook with a fresh kernel.  It ran fine.

Comment: In the notebook experiencing the problem, the definition of coeffVec is apparently corrupted. Erase that line and retype the definition.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon Ah  retyped it and now it is working. Very strange. Would be curious to know how this happens.